# How to set environment variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, bash, typescript, macos, sh

I'm trying to set some environment variables which can be picked up by my bash script.

order of execution:

version.js

```
module.exports.version = function () {
   process.env['APP_VERSION'] = `1.0.0`;
}
```

script.sh

```
run x 
run y
node -e "require('./version.js').version()"
echo "APP_VERSION=$APP_VERSION"
```

but echo output is

```
APP_VERSION=
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is not possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372627/is-it-possible-to-pass-environment-variables-from-child-to-parent-in-user-space). It's not an issue with node, it's just not possible period even any other language. If a child process could modify the environment variables of its parent that would be a huge security issue.

The only reason `export` works in the bash process itself is becuase you run those scripts in the bash process by "sourcing" them so it's modifying its own environment variables.

Example

```
#!/bin/sh
# test.sh
export FOOBAR=Testing
```

```
$ ./test.sh
echo $FOOBAR
```

prints nothing because `test.js` was run in its own process

```
$  source test.sh
echo $FOOBAR
```

prints 'Testing' because in this case test.sh was read and processed by the current bash process itself.

The best you could really do is export a shell script that the shell then executes

```
// example.js
const key = 'FOOBAR';
const value = `hello world: ${(new Date()).toString()}`;
console.log(`export "${key}"="${value}"`)
```

```
node example.js | source /dev/stdin 
echo $FOOBAR
```

But of course that output is specific to the shell you're running in meaning if you switch shells then what you need to output changes. It's also not a normal way to do this.

A more common way might be to output just the value from node

```
run x 
run y
$APP_VERSION=`node -e "console.log(require('./version.js').version())"`
echo "APP_VERSION=$APP_VERSION"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ShellJS](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs).

```js
var shell = require('shelljs');
shell.echo('APP_VERSION="0.0.1"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Dotenv, where you can maintain all the env variables in a file and use the same appropriately, helps in better versioning, since, it Stores configurations in the environment separate from code.

> [Dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) is a zero-dependency module that loads environment variables
>   from a .env file into process.env.

**Usage**
1. Create a .env file

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

2.process.env now has the keys and values you defined in your .env file.

```
const db = require('db')
db.connect({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS
})
```